# How do I compare a dataframe column with another dataframe and create a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. Here is a small sample

```
Days 
4
6
9
1
4
```

My df2 is

```
Day1  Day2 Alphabets
2       5    abc
4       7    bcd
8       10   ghi
10      12   abc
```

I want to change my df1 such that it has new column Alphabets from df2 if the days in df1 is between day1 and day2. Something like:

```
if df1['Days'] in between df2['Day1'] and df2['Day2']:
    df1['Alphabets']=df2['Alphabets']
```

Result is:

```
Days Alphabets
4     abc
6     bcd
9     ghi

etc.
```

I tried for loop and its taking a lot of time even to run. Is there any other elegant way to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I will use `numpy` broadcast

```
s1=df2.Day1.values
s2=df2.Day2.values
s=df1.Days.values[:,None]
df1['V']=((s-s1>0)&(s-s2<0)).dot(df2.Alphabets)
df1
Out[277]: 
   Days    V
0     4  abc
1     6  bcd
2     9  ghi
3     1     
4     4  abc
```